# Rellenar un Polygon en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy haciendo un programita en el cual me he topado con un detalle a la hora de intentar dibujar un polygon en una JPanel en el cual quiero que el color de sus aristas sea totalmente configurable al igual que su fondo.He realizado un intento con el siguiente segmento de codigo:

```
//Coloca color de arista y dibuja figura
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawPolygon(figura);
//Coloca color de fondo y rellena la figura
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillPolygon(figura);
```

Nota.Para no extender mas el codigo la variable figura es de tipo Polygon.

El anterior codigo tambien lo he adaptado de manera muy similar para figuras sin vertices como un circulo.

```
            g.setColor(figu.getColorArista());
            g.drawOval(figu.getCentro().x-radio,figu.getCentro().y-radio,radio*2,radio*2);
            g.setColor(figu.getColorFondo());
            g.fillOval(figu.getCentro().x-radio,figu.getCentro().y-radio,radio*2,radio*2);
```

Sin extender aún mas el programa....Mis resultados no han sido del todo buenos consiguiendo como resultado algo como lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar realmente se ve el cambio de color solo en ciertas orillas de la figura, esto depende de la forma de la figura.He pensado en hacer toda la figura del mismo color y despues simplemente trazar unas lineas que unieran todos los vertices con el color de las aristas de manera que se sobrepongan a la orilla de la figura.Les agradeceria si me compartieran una forma mas formal u otra forma distinta a la planteada que me pudiera dar solucion a este problema,gracias.

Comment: Eso ultimo que dices es exactamente lo que puedes hacer, primero dibujas (rellenas) las figuras con los *fill* y después pintas los contornos con los *draw*, de ese modo los contornos que son los últimos en pintarse serán los que quedan encima de las figuras rellenas de blanco; puedo recomendarte usar `Graphics2D` en vez de `Graphics`.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.Una pregunta mas...He visto que Graphics2D implementa a la inferaz Graphics ,supongo que al yo utilizar Graphics2D tendre acceso a un extra de metodos sin embargo ¿Graphics2D sobrescribe alguno de Graphics? o¿ podria notar la diferencia en como realiza un metodo en un ejemplo como el anterior o la unica ventaja seria que tendria acceso a nuevos metodos?

Comment: `Graphics2D` es un 'nuevo' tipo de objeto `Graphics` y la ventaja es que le permite a uno usar otras características de renderizado un poco mas avanzadas, de la API 2D (si mal no recuerdo el nombre), todo se logra forzando con un cast que el objeto `Graphics` funcione como `Graphics2D`; dentro de los métodos que se pueden utilizar están: `setPaint()`, `setStroke()`, `setRenderingHints()`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy probablemente sirva utilizar primero los atributos *fill* (figuras solidas) y luego dibujar con los *draw* (figuras contorneadas):

```
//Coloca color de fondo y rellena la figura
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillPolygon(figura);
//Coloca color de arista y dibuja figura
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawPolygon(figura);
```

En ese orden de ideas se obtendría algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se aprovechan las ventajas del uso de `Graphics2D` se puede, si se quiere, resaltar la superposición de los 'bordes' de la figura con la ayuda del método `setStroke()` y mejorar el renderizado con `setRenderingHints()`:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
      RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)); //Mejor Renderizado.
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));          //Grosor de Trazado.
g2.setColor(figu.getColorFondo());
g2.fillOval(figu.getCentro().x-radio,figu.getCentro().y-radio,radio*2,radio*2);
g2.setColor(figu.getColorArista());
g2.drawOval(figu.getCentro().x-radio,figu.getCentro().y-radio,radio*2,radio*2);
```

Con lo cual se obtiene, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ambos, tanto `RenderingHints()` como `BasicStroke()` están en `java.awt`